# The previous system shutdown at xxxx was unexpected

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

For the past two nights we had a remote server shutdown unexpectedly.  When rebooted we get the following message:

> Event Type:   Error    Event
>   Source:   EventLog    Event
>   Category: None 
>   Event ID: 6008
>   Date:     16/02/2011
>   Time:     09:10:43
>   User:     N/A
>   Computer: WELPLAN-1
>   Description:   The previous system
>   shutdown at 07:27:32 on 16/02/2011 was
>   unexpected.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>   Data:
>   0000: db 07 02 00 03 00 10 00 Û.......
>   0008: 07 00 1b 00 20 00 42 02 .... .B.
>   0010: db 07 02 00 03 00 10 00 Û.......
>   0018: 07 00 1b 00 20 00 42 02 .... .B.

Obviously this message doesn't help much, but what does all the hexadecimal mean?  Will it help me track down the problem?  Any pointers as to where to look?

Comment: what kind of hardware is this server on?

Comment: Intel(R) Core 2 CPU 6700@2.66GHz with 4GB of RAM

Comment: sorry i should have clarified, is it dell/hp/white box?

Comment: I haven't the slightest - its hosted remotely but its our own dedicated server

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already checked for stop error (i.e. a bugcheck).

If event 6006 appears prior to the shutdown the machine stopped gracefully and Windows is misreporting it as a dirty shutdown.

If event 6006 is not present, it's likely the result of a hardware failure. Because you dont have direct access to manage the hardware, you'll need to open a ticket with your provider to investigate the hardware.